# SignalR - enumerate available hubs and hub methods from .NET client

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

Is there (or will be) a way to enumerate all the available hubs (and their methods) client-side, using C# client? Haven't seen anything like that in the `SignalR.Client` library, but maybe I'm missing something?

There's no problem in doing that in JS client, though, as all info is already here in the JS code.

If it's impossible so maybe there are plans on implementing such feature? Or if it cannot be done out-of-the-box, maybe there is a workaround for that?

Comment: Re: Edit: You can do it yourself.

Comment: Yes, I know that and it's a workaround I'll stick to (custom URL with hubs info exposed as JSON).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's inherently impossible to enumerate client methods on the server, since the clients never send their method names to the server.

Instead, you can have the client script loop over its object and send the list of methods to the server yourself.

Comment: I guess you meant the opposite - it's impossible to enumerate hub methods on the client, right? Hub is on the server side - you can enumerate those on server side without any problems. If that's what you meant, it's like I thought...

Comment: You're right; I got mixed up.  (I've never actually used Signalr yet)

Comment: Yes that's correct. We'd need to expose a schema but we're not doing this for 0.5. Maybe the next version.

Comment: @dfowler Ok, thanks. I'll setup a rest URL and expose a list of hubs in JSON - will be ok for a workaround.

Comment: @SLaks You're talking about something completely different - I don't want to enumerate client methods (event subscriptions) on the server, but to get the server schema (available hubs and methods), as David Fowler pointed out.